# Angular 7 - download incoming file from server

Tags: angular

I am sending a post request to my back end to receive an excell file. I can see in postman that my backend is sending the excell, but in angular I cannot download it. any ideas?
here is my html code:

```
<button (click)="excell()">Export Excell</button>
```

here is my service class:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor(private data: DataService , private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) { }

  ngOnInit()  {

    }

    excell(){this.data.excell() 
    console.log("sent")}



}
```

and here is my data class method for requesting to backend:

```
excell() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    console.log("sentin")
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/Excel', { headers: headers })
  }
```

Comment: storing file at server and sending the file path to download using anchor tag in frontend had worked for me.

Comment: I've used FileSaver: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ in the past to save blobs coming back from APIs, and it's worked well for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
textFileDownload() {
    this.httpClient.get('url', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
    .subscribe((res) => {
        this.writeContents(res, 'test.txt', 'text/txt'); // file extension
    });
}

writeContents(content, fileName, contentType) {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    const file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
  }
```

Comment: Dear @m-waqas-rc can you please elaborate your answer? 

Kind regards